# Probability distribution for absolute deviation

Tags: probability, mean, proportion

Sample of a 25 soldiers was asked if they eat a breakfast daily

And necessery to find probabily distrubution where the proportion of soldiers that eat a breafast daily will not be different more than 0.3 from a mean.

Solution :
I  use a $ \widehat{p} $  parametr - sample proportion ,  sample size is $n=25$
, $\widehat{p}=\frac{x}{25}$

In a proportions , the mean , $\mu=\frac{n\cdot p}{n}=p$

Using a Chebyshev's inequality :
$P(\left | \widehat{p}-p \right |< \varepsilon )\geqslant 1-\frac{1}{4\cdot n\cdot \varepsilon^{2} }$

$P(\left | \widehat{p}-p \right |< 0.3 )\geqslant 1-\frac{1}{4\cdot 25\cdot 0.3^{2} }$

The probabiluty sould be more or equal than $\frac{8}{9}$

Is my way right ?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean by different more than 0.3 from a mean. Can you try to re-express it? Why are you using Chebyshev's inequality rather than some method based on a normal approximation?

Comment: for a small sample size less then 30 the normal approximation would not be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\hat p$ has a distribution with mean $p$ and variance $\sigma^2 = \frac{p (1-p)}{n} \le \frac{1}{4n}$.

Chebyshev's inequality can also be written as:
\begin{align}
\Pr( \lvert \hat p - p \rvert > \varepsilon)
&\le \frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}
\le \frac{1}{4 n \varepsilon^2}
\end{align}
so that when $n = 25$, $\varepsilon = .3$ we get
$$
\Pr( \lvert \hat p - p \rvert > .3)
\le \frac{1}{4(25)(.09)} = \frac{1}{9}
.$$
So, yes, your argument is correct (assuming that your sample is a correct random sample).